# Uncaught TypeError: Property getPos of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures

Why can't I get the `pos` form the `box`?

I'm trying to learn JavaSCript, using namespace, and Modular pattern while making a simple game.

I've made `point`, `box` and `Squares`(the game) objects.

I build 3 `box'es` and put them into the game object (`Squares`) for later use, but when I try to access the pos I only get "Uncaught TypeError: Property getPos of object # is not a function".

First I thought the type of the box is wrong and maybe I should check it(but I don't know if it's even possible). And they I  thought JavaScript is a dynamic language, so it shouldn't be nessesary.
I'm obviously confused and stranded. What am I missing or lack to understand?

Running code example: or see [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ybwyLdmj/)

```
var myNS = myNS || {};

myNS.point = function (x, y) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
};

myNS.box = function (pos) {
    // private members
    getPos = function () {
        return pos;
    };

    // public memebers
    return {
        getPos: getPos()
    };
};

myNS.Squares = function() {
    // private members
        var boxes,

            getBoxes = function() {
                return boxes;
            }

            setBoxes = function(newBoxes) {
                boxes = newBoxes;
            };

    // public memebers
    return {
        getBoxes: getBoxes,
        setBoxes: setBoxes
    };
}('canvasSquares');

$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').append('Initialize.. <br/>');
    init();
    $('body').append('Initialize done. <br/> <br/>');

    useBoxesLater();
});

function init() {
    var boxes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var pos = myNS.point(10 * i, 10 * i);
        var box = myNS.box(pos);
        boxes.push(box);
        $('body').append('box added: ' + pos.x + ', ' + pos.y + '<br/> ');
    }
    $('body').append('boxes: ' + boxes.length + '<br/>');

    myNS.Squares.setBoxes(boxes);
};

function useBoxesLater(){
    var boxes = myNS.Squares.getBoxes();
    $('body').append('boxes in myNS.Squares: ' + boxes.length + '<br/>');
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        $('body').append(i + '. box: ' + box + '<br/>');

        $('body').append('Find pos on box: <br/>');
        $('body').append('Calling box.getPos() result in Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Property getPos of object #<Object> is not a function"');
        var pos = box.getPos();

        $('body').append('<br/>');
    }

    $('body').append('Don\'t get to here');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening on this line:

```
var pos = box.getPos();
```

Based on your myNS.box definition, getPos is not returning a function but the pos object, e.g {x:0, y:0}.

Change the return of `getPos: getPos()` to `getPos: getPos`.

```
// public memebers
return {
    getPos: getPos
};
```

After that, you can call pos.x and pos.y.

Update fiddle with working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ybwyLdmj/1/